# XPath format a date of an attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I want the following node

```
 <forecast-period index="1" start-time-local="2016-04-25T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2016-04-26T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2016-04-24T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2016-04-25T14:00:00Z">
```

to be formatted as followed 'Tuesday 26 April'

So far I have the following, but cant seem to get it to work

Cheers

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-date(document('IDN11050.xml')//area[@description='Sydney']/forecast-period[@index='1']/@start-time-local, '*not sure what to put here* ' )"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question lacks context. If you are in the context of the `forecast-period` element, you can use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(@start-time-local, '[F], [D] [MNn]')" />
```

to return:

```
Monday, 25 April
```

Comment: what do you mean by lacks context? sorry im sorta new to xpath. is the commar supposed to be there?

Comment: The comma is optional (it outputs a comma after Monday). What is the error message?

Comment: I am using mozilla firefox (im a newbee to xml/xsl/xpath) . It just says Error loading stylesheet: Invalid XSLT/XPath function.

Comment: @seus: If you are using `FireFox` you are unable to use `format-dateTime`, because this is an XSLT-2.0 function and `FireFox` only supports XSLT-1.0. So this answer is useless to you.

Comment: If you're using a browser, then you're not using XSLT 2.0, and cannot use the `format-date()` or `format-dateTime` functions.